# Dropwizard filter priority - Customer Filter vs CORs filter

Tags: java, jersey, jsonp, dropwizard

I currently have two filters in my dropwizard app.
One is CORs and the other filter is custom filter that checks header for any resource request to see if custom authorization token in the header is valid.  Individual filter works well without the other, but when I combine these two together always custom filter kicks in first.  I want CORs to be resolved before Custom filter kicks in.  Because when I call API from javascript, it requires CORs.  JSONP does bypass requirement of CORs, but it does not let you pass custom header over.

Oh I tried to use @Priority as well, but I can see how I can apply @Priority to my custom filter, but CORs is already defined and I am not sure how I can apply Priority.

If you need additional info, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: It has been few days and I haven't seen any response and I am wondering if my question wasn't clear enough to be answered by experts.  If you see this post, can you give me some feedback, so I can add additional help?

Comment: What are your CORS and your Custom Filter implementations? I.e. did you use a Servlet Filter or Jersey Filter implementation for your Custom Filter? Are you using Jetty's out of box CrossOriginFilter class for CORS or wrote your ow? Also what version of Dropwizard and how are you registering both of these Filters?